# Strong Principle of Induction

Tags: real-analysis, induction

What is the proof of the Strong Principle of Induction? Why can we assume that a principle holds up to "n," least of all "n+1"? When can we make this assumption and when can we not?

Comment: Apparently it's an AXIOM equivalent to the "well-ordering principle" : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Equivalence_with_the_well-ordering_principle

Comment: you seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding here. What is the assumption that you're questioning?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I wouldn't say questioning so much as unsure why the principle is true (intuitively). From my understanding, it seems that so long as for a property you can prove the base case and the nth case, the property holds for all natural numbers. But how do you prove the nth case (I know it's a bit ambiguous because we're not talking about any specific property)?

Comment: @Aaron This is the misunderstanding I was alluding to. You don't prove the base case and the nth case. You prove the base case and the induction step. The induction step is not that $P(n)$ is true... that would be proving the whole thing. The statement you must prove for the induction step (in strong induction) is 'if $P(k)$ is true for all $k<n,$ then $P(n)$ is true". Notice it is a conditional statement

Comment: Also I feel like I'm still not 100% understanding your confusion (though you clarified a bunch in your previous reply)... does this have anything specifically to do with *strong* induction, or could you ask this question about the other form of induction, where the induction step is "if $P(n)$ holds then $P(n+1)$ holds"?

Answer (score 1):

Taking the domain of naturals as implicit, Strong induction is the principle that:$$P(0)~,~\forall n\Big(\big(\forall m\leq n: P(m)\big)\to P(n+1)\Big) \vdash \forall n\in\Bbb N:P(n)$$

**If** the predicate holds in the base case, and it is true that the predicate will hold for *any* natural is a logical consequence of it holding for *all* prior numbers , **then** the predicate shall hold for *any* natural number.

> Why can we assume that a principle holds up to "n," least of all "n+1"?

The assumption you make is that $P(m)$ holds for all $m$ up to an arbitrary $n$.   You then seek to demonstrate, through some *valid argument*, that $P(n+1)$ will be a *logical consequence* of that assumption.   This forms a conditional proof that the *implication* is true for all $n$.